# Sorting algorithm in Haskell

Tags: sorting, haskell, quicksort

I am trying to implement a very trivial sorting algorithm in Haskell. It compiles but keeps giving me incorrect outputs.

Here is the code

```
import Data.List

minimum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
minimum' (x:xs) = foldr (\ x y -> if x <= y then x else y) x xs

qsrt :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
qsrt [] = []
qsrt l@(x:xs) = minimum' l : qsrt xs
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What leads you to believe that `qsrt` would sort the list? Which sorting algorithm are you trying to implement?

Comment: Well, I am only a novice. My thinking was, if I pattern match on (x:xs) extract the smallest element of that list and cons it with a recursion on the same function of the tail of the list I would eventually end up with a sorted list.. But the logic is clearly incorrect. None in particular. Just refactoring some functions myself for academic purposes.

Comment: `qsrt` takes the minimum element of `l` and then skips `x`, but `x` would only be the minimum element of `l` by accident so you're usually skipping the wrong element.

Comment: Doesnt l@(x:xs) represent the entire list?

Comment: `l` represents the entire list, `x` the head and `xs` the tail.

Comment: @Rein Henrichs  I understand what you meant. How thick of me. x is not necessarily the smallest element in the list and I am completely removing it from the equation.

Comment: You're probably trying to implement *selection sort*. Try `let qsrt [] = []; qsrt l = let y = minimum' l in y : qsrt (delete y l)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The logic error is that `qsrt` takes the minimum element of `l` and then skips `x`, but `x` would only be the minimum element of `l` by accident so you're usually skipping the wrong element.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addendum to Rein Henrichs's answer, I managed to craft a correct version of the above using a filter.

```
import Data.List

minimum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a
minimum' (x:xs) = foldl' (\ x y -> if x <= y then x else y) x xs

srt :: (Ord a) => [a] -> [a]
srt [] = []
srt l = ml : srt (delete ml l)
    where ml = minimum' l
```

Comment: This will give wrong results if the list contains duplicate elements.

Comment: @Franky Thanks for pointing it out. It should work as intended now.